# Environment variable working in run but not cmd

Tags: windows-8, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up a phonegap android app (that's incidental, just some introduction), and there's a batch file called android.bat I need to be able to run globally. If I put "android" in cmd, it should run the batch file. I've set it in the "path" environment variable, restarted cmd and restarted the computer to no avail- putting "android" in cmd results in "android is not recognised as an internal or external command" etc.

What's very odd is that before setting the environment variable, running "android" from Run didn't work, whereas now it does. So clearly Windows recognises it as a valid global variable. And if I put the full path into cmd, it works fine.

Also, when I create another batch file in a different location and attempt the same, that gets the same results.

So I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to say that, but, what needs to be put in path is the folder in where android batch file is located. Is this what you have done?

Comment: Yep. To elaborate, this is the exact text in the PATH: C:\Users\david_000\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools. That's where the batch file is.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Putting" android in cmd? What environment variable did you set - to what?

To run `android.bat` from the prompt, you need to ensure that `android.bat` is located in one of the directories in your `PATH`.

To see your `PATH` simply enter `PATH` at the prompt. You will be shown a semicolon-separated list of the directories. Put `ANDOID.BAT` in any one of those directories, or add a new directory (c:\belfry is popular) and include that in your PATH.

Having said that, the very first directory examined by `CMD` is the CURRENT directory, so `ANDROID` would run as a command if `android.bat` is in your current directory, even if it isn't in a directory on the `PATH`.

Comment: It's in a directory in the PATH- I added the directory to my user's PATH.

Comment: Changing `PATH` only affects the current instance of `CMD`. Changing `path` in the registry only affects FUTURE instances of `CMD` - not those already running. Perhaps that would explain your observation.

Comment: Hence why I always restart CMD when I've changed the variable, having noticed this in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Just to resume that i've understand everything

1 - There is a batch file (android.bat/cmd)

2 - Calling it directly with full path, it runs without problems

3 - Calling it from run dialog, it runs without problems (actually it's the same case as point 2 for the way it works)

4 - The directory in where the batch file is located is included in path

5 - Calling it from another directory it does not work

6 - The same occurs for other batch files

Two possibilities.

Path variable contains a non valid or non properly quoted/escaped character and the system have problems to find programs in path.

Or, .CMD or .BAT are not included in PATHEXT variable. It list the extensions that are checked in each directory of path when calling a program.

From a command line, type `SET PATH` and check if any of this two options is correct.

EDITED

Seems these options doesn't locate the problem. Lets try something different

Find the file `sdk\tools\lib\find_java.bat` in your sdk. Change the lines (should be 26 and 32 approx.)

```
for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -s') do set java_exe=%%a
for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -s -w') do set javaw_exe=%%a
```

To

```
for /f %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s') do set java_exe=%%a
for /f %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s -w') do set javaw_exe=%%a
```

And then try again to run android.bat

Comment: Mostly right. For 3, when I call it from run dialog, I'm just putting "android" in the dialog, and that works, so clearly it's recognising it from the PATH.

It is in there- .BAT is one of the extensions in the list. Also, I just tried the SET PATH, echoed it and it found it. I'm not sure if there's a batch file example I can use within System32 to demonstrate whether it's something I've done wrong (which it probably is).

Comment: @user2564511, no, for point 3 [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used. No need for the application to be in the path. I keep thinking ...

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the PATH, but as I said, it didn't work until I put it in the PATH. So clearly it is recognising the PATH as being valid.

Comment: I think your edited solution might be assuming a different version than the one I've got- mine has the following by default:

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s') do set java_exe=%%a; 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s -w') do set javaw_exe=%%a